# Constructing basis for C[a,b]

Tags: functional-analysis

For the following question:

Let $a<b$.  Show that every basis for $C[a,b]$ is uncountable by exhibiting an uncountable linearly independent subset in $C[a,b]$
and

Can I construct the linearly independent set as constituting elements from the range of the following function $f_x$ where it is defined as:

$f(x)=0, \text{ for }x=1, f(x)=1  \text{ for, }x=0, \text{ and }f(x)=x \text{ for }x\in (0,1)\cap (\mathbb{R}\setminus\mathbb{Q})$

Also, since the basis for $C[a,b]$ has an uncountable number of elements, does that mean any elements in $C[a,b]$ can still be written as a finite linear combination of elements from the basis?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Your notation is very confused and confusing: when you write $f_x(x)$, the two $x$s are different. I think that the functions $f_x$  tht you trying to define aren't continuous. Why not consider constant functions? By definition, if $B$ is a basis for a vector space $V$ every element of $V$ is a finite linear combination of elements of $B$.

Comment: @RobArthan how about the following function: $f(x)=0, \text{ for }x=1, f(x)=1  \text{ for, }x=0, \text{ and }f(x)=x \text{ for }x\in (0,1)\cap (\mathbb{R}\setminus\mathbb{Q})$,  I also edited the post to reflect the changes.  Would the range of $f$ be linearly independent and also continuous?

Comment: You're supposed to exhibit an uncountable linearly independent set of *functions*. What does a *single* function (or the range of, or whatever else you suggest) have to do with it? (When "eaten", consider e.g. $\{x\mapsto|x-c| : c\in(a,b)\}$.)

Comment: @metamorphy am I suppose to exhibit a collection of different functions over C[a, b] which collectively constitute an independent subset.  Or am I suppose to use the range from a single function to build up the linearly independent subset?

Comment: Ok. What is *your* set of *functions*?

Comment: @RobArthan how about $u_{\lambda}(t)=e^{t\lambda}$, for $t, \lambda \in [a,b]$.

Comment: @metamorphy I just came up with a function in my previous comment and not sure if it does the job.

Comment: That looks good. I don't think you need the restriction $\lambda \in [a, b]$.

Comment: @RobArthan, when you suggested constant functions   Did you mean the following $u_t(x)=tk$, for constant $k$ and $t, x \in [a,b]$?

Comment: I meant $u_t(x) = t$, but it was a dumb suggestion. Apologies for that.

Comment: @RobArthan no worries.  And thank you for all your help.